# Ползунок с возможностью ввода значений

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rangeslider

Есть обычный ползунок на jQuery Ui .slide(). 
Но требуется что бы реагировал на ввод данных вручную. Сейчас если вводишь данные в поле то ползунок никак не принимает эти данные. Подскажите пожалуйста как ползунку передавать эти данные?

```js
$(function() {

  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [75, 300],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#price").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#price").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<input class="form-control" name="price" id="price">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что проверки на корректность додумаете:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [75, 300],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#price").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#price").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
  $("#price").on('input', function() {
    let aRange = $(this).val().split(' - ');
    $("#slider-range").slider({
      values: [aRange[0].replace(/\D/g, ''), aRange[1].replace(/\D/g, '')]
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="price" id="price">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```